# Как разместить несколько сайтов(express.js) на одном сервере с разными доменами?

Tags: node.js, express, devops

Необходимо на одном сервере, с одним ip, запустить два сайта на node.js с разными доменами на 80'ом порту. Как к этому подходить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254583/how-do-i-host-multiple-node-js-sites-on-the-same-ip-server-with-different-domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я обычно использую стараюсь использовать универсальные решения и в данном случае это любой из web серверов. Например, Nginx. Вот [статья](https://www.8host.com/blog/nastrojka-nginx-dlya-podderzhki-odnogo-i-neskolkix-sajtov-wordpress/) описывающая, как это сделать.

В папке `/etc/nginx/sites-available` мы создаем нужное нам количество файлов-конфигураций (или делаем на них ссылки). Каждый из файлов у нас будет примерно такой:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name sitename.ru; # указать свой сайт

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_redirect off;
        }

        # сюда дописываем конфиги
}
```

То есть, мы указываем порт, на котором висит данный сайт и порт (`proxy_pass`), на котором висит нужное node.js приложение и на который будет перебрасываться входящий запрос.